# undefined local variable or method `user', using CarrierWave for profile images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, carrierwave

I've been following Ryan Bates' Railscasts tutorial on CarrierWave, which you can find [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads)

Everything works fine, except for when I go to view my profile, it gives me this error:

`` undefined local variable or method `user' ``

I don't know why it is telling me this, as I am using Devise for my authentication, and that is the name of my model.

Below are some of the files which may be useful:

https://gist.github.com/amarh21/7439421

I am using Rails 4.0.1 and ruby 2.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should share your controller. Anyway, I think that the problem is not Carrierwave. Looks like the problem is you are not setting the variable correctly. In your controller you should have something:

```
def profile
  user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

You have to use an instance variable, an instance variable has a name beginning with @, and its scope is confined to whatever object self refers to. So, replace `user` by `@user` in the controller and view:

```
def profile
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

<%= image_tag @user.profile_image_url %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. I did have that block of code in my profile controller. In my page, I added @user.profile_image, and now there is no error. But, there is now no image showing. Any ideas why?

Comment: Maybe you don't have an image. Check the HTML code (image src) and in console try: `User.find("the_user_id").profile_image_url`.

Comment: Make sure you added `profile_image_url` with the `url` sufix.

Comment: I tried that command, but it returns nil, even though I uploaded an image. Where would the image be stored? I could try looking there, which would isolate the problem to the image tag?

Comment: Yes, the problem is you don't have image. In your `ProfileImageUploader` you definded the `store_dir`. Take a look in `public/uploads/user/profile_image/user-id`.

Comment: It says that there is no directory there?